# discord.py Output prefix

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi I am trying to output my bot prefix in on_ready event

```
from nextcord.ext import commands
import datetime
import asyncio
import humanfriendly
import aiosqlite

async def getprefix(bot, message):
    async with aiosqlite.connect("prefixs.db") as db:
        async with db.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute('SELECT prefix FROM Prefixs WHERE guild = ?', (message.guild.name,))
            data = await cursor.fetchone()
            if data:
                return data
            else:
                try:
                    await cursor.execute('INSERT INTO prefixs (prefix, guild) VALUES (?, ?)', ('!', message.guild.name,))
                    await cursor.execute('SELECT prefix FROM prefixs WHERE guild = ?', (message.guild.id,))
                    data = await cursor.fetchone()
                    if data:
                        await cursor.execute('UPDATE prefixs SET prefix = ? WHERE guild = ? ', ('!', message.guild.name,))
                except Exception:
                    return '!'

bot = commands.Bot(intents=nextcord.Intents.all(), command_prefix=getprefix, help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'The current prefix for this server is{getprefix}')
    print(f'Der Bot ist als {bot.user.name} Online')
    async with aiosqlite.connect("prefixs.db") as db:
        async with db.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prefixs (prefix TEXT, guild ID)')
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task())
```

I have tried this: `print(f'The current prefix for this server is{getprefix}')`
but it only comes: `The current prefix for this server is<function getprefix at 0x0000008C916AA3B0>` could someone help me am still very new to python

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the call to the method.

It seems like you made the getprefix() method with a `message` parameter, but if you're calling the method from the `on_ready()` event, you can't pass a message parameter.

You could call the method from a prefix command like this.

```py
@bot.command()
async def showprefix(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"My prefix is {await getprefix(ctx.guild)}")
```

```py
async def getprefix(guild):
    async with aiosqlite.connect("prefixs.db") as db:
        async with db.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute('SELECT prefix FROM Prefixs WHERE guild = ?', (guild.name,))
```

And one last tip: Guild names can be duplicate. It's better to use the ID of the guild for the database.